# ASP.NET Web Application Project only shows VB options, not C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm working on a project and I'm fairly new to ASP (not to C#).

We have a solution for a whole web application consisting of several projects and I want to add a couple of ASP WebForms to one of the projects. However, when I right click on the folder of the project and select Add element, it only shows me VB options.

[image: Only VB options appears]

But if I try to add other project to the solution, then all the other options are displayed.

[image: Other options, yayyy]

The project in which I'm trying to add new Web Forms is entirely written in C#, so I don't know well what's happening back there. I cannot stop thinking it might a dumb mistake I'm making.
I'm working under Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 4.7.2. It is there some kind of requirement I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your time and sorry if it's something simpler, but I really don't know what's going on here.

Comment: I forgot to mention that is a Web Application Project, not a Web Site one, or at least that what the CodeBehind tags on the .aspx files suggests.

Comment: It means you created the project as a VB.NET Web Application project (it will have a `.vbproj` file). Create a new separate C# Web Application project and look inside the `.csproj` and spot the differences (such as the project-type GUIDs)

Comment: Also, it's 2020. **You should not be using ASP.NET WebForms for new projects**. It's a decades-old deprecated (and now obsolete) platform.

Comment: The first screenshot you posted is from the "Add Item" dialog, the second screenshot is from the "Add Project" dialog. Projects and Items are different things.

Comment: I didn't create the project, I need to add a couple of things on it. About the ASP.NET WebForms, is a requirement, it isn't up to me

Comment: @Dai there is not a vbproj, just a .csproj.user in that project folder.

Comment: The project-type GUIDs in your `.sln` or `.csproj` may be incorrect (e.g. another dev using a `.vbproj` project-type GUID to add VB-specific project items) - or your VS install is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, this looks like that one application was created as a vb.net application.

You can freely consume say c# code (assemblies) in a vb.net project. And of course you can do the reverse.

However, for a given project created? You can't at the IDE level mix vb.net and c# code modules and general writing of code between c# and vb.net.

However, as in your example, you can certainly "include" multiple mixes of vb.net and c# projects into one same project. However, each part and section will still be limited to the chosen language used to build that application. So mixing is allowed at the project level - but not below that level.

So, it looks to be that project was created and developed with vb.net. You can't really change that unless you create a new project as c#, and then pull in all the forms, code etc. and re-factor the vb.net to c#.

So your practical project language choice is really limited to the project level. Multiple projects of different languages can be included overall, but each part will remain in its given language choice. The fact that you can do this in .net is amazing enough, but that language choice is really set in stone at the project level.

Comment: Its somewhat weird. If I open this project in itself (not the whole solution) it'll let me add C# elements.

Answer (score 0):

While you're figuring it out, if you need to press on and get some work done just copypaste another file that is already in the solution, and is of the type you require, then change its contents. This can usually be a time saver anyway, as the "new product" form isn't so hugely different from the "new user" form, just a different bunch of labels and textboxes..

There is nothing magical about the "add new item" dialog, it just adds files with pre filled templated content. For a cs class (for example) that's a file that basically has a detected namespace and the name you specified in the add dialog.  You could even add a VB file of the type you want and then change the contents and name of the file to be right for C# - it would essentially be adding a couple of curly brackets and changing the case of Namespace and Class (and maybe changing Imports to using)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix languages in the same assembly in .Net. Create another assembly you can put your C# code in there and use it in the VB.Net project.

Or use VB.Net it's not that bad.